# JS: Using apply rather than call with prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript

If I am inheriting the properties of Person below, how could I do this without passing in individual properties using `apply`.  Wouldn't Person have to be changed to accept an array of args rather than individual properties?

```
function Person(age, name) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;

}

function Man(gender,age,name) {
     this.gender = gender;
     Person.call(this, gender,age);

}

Man.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)
```

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which takes an array of arguments? [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) takes arguments not in an array, just like what you're doing. Although there seems to be a discrepancy between `Person(age, name)` and your `call` arguments `gender,age`...

Comment: Why don't you use [`class`es](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class)? `class Person { ... }; class Man extends Person { ... }`